# Add stars to p-values and put standard errors in parenthesis

Tags: r, dataframe

```
 structure(list(rowname = c("Coefficient", "Standard error", "Observations", 
"75% Coefficient", "Standard error", "Observations", "125% Coefficient", 
"Standard error", "Observations", "Optimal Bandwidth", "75% Optimal Bandwidth", 
"125% Optimal Bandwidth"), tri = c(-0.127, 0.072, 436, -0.305, 
0.088, 132, -0.133, 0.089, 281, 0.107, 0.047, 0.079), pvalue1 = c(0.078, 
NA, NA, 0.001, NA, NA, 0.135, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), uni = c(0.064, 
0.028, 444, 0.117, 0.023, 382, 0.043, 0.024, 560, 0.083, 0.138, 
0.138), pvalue2 = c(0.023, NA, NA, 0, NA, NA, 0.07, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

I have the above table. I want to add stars to coefficients by available p-values in columns pvalue1 and pvalue2. For example
-0.127* , 0.064**, -0.305***
Also, all standard error should be in parenthesis , for example (0.072), (0.088).
Thank you!

Comment: what are the thresholds you want to add stars for?

Comment: I ask because -0.1 isn't a valid p number

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want the stars to be at 10%, 5%, and 1%, here is how you can do that:

```
library(dplyr)
df |> mutate(across(starts_with("pvalue"), # for each pvalue column,
        ~ ifelse(grepl("Coefficient", rowname), { # if the rowname includes "Coefficient"
            # figure out the ending we'll be adding
            v <- case_when(.x < 0.1 ~ "*",
                           .x < 0.05 ~ "**",
                           .x < 0.01 ~ "***",
                            TRUE ~ "")
            # add the ending
            paste0(.x, v)}, as.character(.x))),
            across(c(tri, uni), ~ ifelse(grepl("Standard error", rowname), paste0("(", .x, ")"), as.character(.x))))
```

Output:

```
                  rowname     tri pvalue1     uni pvalue2
1             Coefficient  -0.127  0.078*   0.064  0.023*
2          Standard error (0.072)    <NA> (0.028)    <NA>
3            Observations     436    <NA>     444    <NA>
4         75% Coefficient  -0.305  0.001*   0.117      0*
5          Standard error (0.088)    <NA> (0.023)    <NA>
6            Observations     132    <NA>     382    <NA>
7        125% Coefficient  -0.133   0.135   0.043   0.07*
8          Standard error (0.089)    <NA> (0.024)    <NA>
9            Observations     281    <NA>     560    <NA>
10      Optimal Bandwidth   0.107    <NA>   0.083    <NA>
11  75% Optimal Bandwidth   0.047    <NA>   0.138    <NA>
12 125% Optimal Bandwidth   0.079    <NA>   0.138    <NA>
```

Comment: Your code has a small bug, one star for all level of significance. -0.127 should have 1 star, -0.305 with 2 stars and -0.133 with no stars. How to fix that issue, thanks! P-values are in pvalue1 and pvalue2. "tri" and "uni" are different estimations of coefficients.

Comment: right, but which significance levels do you want to use?

Comment: I would like to use the standard 10, 5 and 1 percent significance as you did above. Thanks!

Comment: So you are asking for the coefficients to be given the p-value stars?

Comment: Yes correct. Please let me know how to fix the stars. Thank you again!